# Syntax for pushing a value to GTM DataLayer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, data-layer

Please advise on how to push to GTM dataLayer the value below step by step (I'm not a developer).

```
document.getElementById("mytdId").innerText
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a way around which works , here the snippet :

```
Hi 

    function (){ 
var topMenu = document.getElementById("dm1m0i1tdT").innerText;
return(topMenu);
}
```

To improve the syntax you suggest  an array but  don't know how to handle that in this case here. Any suggestion  ?